# python (selenium) get url before button click

Tags: python, selenium

The url is generated when the button is clicked, the html code of the button does not contain href. Is it possible to get the link or url before clicking?

```
<button _ngcontent-svx-c237="" placement="top" 
class="btn-edit ng-star-inserted" 
tabindex="0"><tsl-svg-icon _ngcontent-svx-c237="" 
src="/assets/icons/btn-edit.svg">
<svg width="29" height="29" viewBox="0 0 29 29" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" display="flex">
<g id="Artboard" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" 
transform="translate(-82 -12)"><path d="M103.834 21.27l-1.31 1.31-2.978-2.977 1.31-1.311a.485.485 0 0 1 .348-.141.54.54 0 0 1 .385.162l2.225 2.224a.52.52 0 0 1 .02.733zM88.717 33.898a.247.247 0 0 1-.335-.322l1.715-3.961 2.449 2.449-3.829 1.834zm9.912-13.379l2.978 2.978-7.874 7.87a.145.145 0 0 1-.099-.048l-2.827-2.826c-.048-.049-.05-.096-.055-.096l7.877-7.878zm6.101-.898l-2.225-2.225a1.837 1.837 0 0 0-1.301-.541c-.46 0-.917.173-1.264.52L89.835 27.48a1.261 1.261 0 0 0-.209.289.632.632 0 0 0-.268.288l-2.165 5.003a1.55 1.55 0 0 0 .346 1.727 1.548 1.548 0 0 0 1.737.28l5.022-2.406a.633.633 0 0 0 .317-.345c.01-.01.021-.016.03-.025l10.105-10.105c.704-.703.694-1.851-.02-2.565z" id="Fill-1" fill="#607D8B"></path></g></svg></tsl-svg-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: In my view, when the url is generated after clicking on the button, then it is not possible to get it before it is generated, i.e., before clicking. Moreover, if the url is not seen in the DOM, then you cannot get the href since href is the attribute of the element, and if no href is created, you wouldn't get it. Does clicking on the button create a new page with a url? if yes, you can get `driver.currenturl()` (after clicking on the button and going to the relevant page)

Comment: @AnandGautam I am facing this same situation, but I don't want to go to the next page. This is because I have a list of times I need to get their URL on this page. Also, this list has a pagination. The next content is generated by js and there is a URL change. The only URL change is when I click on one of the items.